How do I paste bash commands that contain sudo into a gnome-terminal?
I like to copy/paste bash commands when building a new system to make things go faster.  Years ago, I set this up, and I could use the mouse to select many dozens of commands that I would then paste into gnome-terminal. I would let them run to completion before pasting in the next batch. This worked fine for years.
Then (Fedora 39 I think) this stopped working. I could still copy and paste, but execution would stop once a sudo command was executed. The remaining command would echo to the screen but would not execute.
Environment:

Platform: X86_64
O/S : Fedora 40
Kernel: 6.9.9-200
Bash: GNU bash, version 5.2.26(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
gnome-terminal: 3.50.1
sudoers: User is listed with (ALL=ALL) never prompt for password

How to reproduce:
Copy these commands and paste into a terminal:
sudo ls
date
sudo ps
sudo uname -a

Expected output:
The expected output is the output of the four commands. The actual output is the output of the ls command and that is it. The other commands are not executed.
Workarounds:
Right now, I can still copy and paste, but only until and including the next sudo command. This is slowing me down tremendously, as there hundreds of commands to execute. Pasting all the commands into a .bash file and executing does work.  Pasting all the commands into a text file and sourceing it works as well.
What I am asking for:
I have done a ton of research over the last year or so and have gotten nowhere. I am asking here because I finally got frustrated enough to ask for help. What I would like is to go back to the old behavior, that is before whatever 'new feature' caused this copy/paste execution to stop working.

Does the behavior improve after bind 'set enable-bracketed-paste on'?

I'm sure they're asking to turn it off rather than on.

It was off.  I set it off last year I think to fix a similar problem.  I turned it on, and now it echos all the commands to the screen, and after I hit enter it executes them all.  I don't see what output goes wityh what command

@JohnW "I don't see what output goes with what command" – If this needs to be fixed then you should edit the question and update the "expected output" paragraph. For now "after I hit enter it executes them all" fulfills the requirement ("The expected output is the output of the four commands").

Analysis
A possible cause may be the use_pty flag. See man 5 sudoers [emphasis mine]:

use_pty
If set, and sudo is running in a terminal, the command will be run in a new pseudo-terminal. If the sudo process is not attached to a terminal, use_pty has no effect.
A malicious program run under sudo may be capable of injecting commands into the user's terminal or running a background process that retains access to the user's terminal device even after the main program has finished executing. By running the command in a separate pseudo-terminal, this attack is no longer possible. This flag is on by default for sudo 1.9.14 and above.

With use_pty sudo acts as a relay and it will read its stdin as soon as possible, even if the inner command is not going to read its stdin. The situation is similar to what ssh does.
The default behavior changed in the past; this explains why things stopped working for you.

Solution
You can restore the old behavior. Start an elevated shell with sudo -i, let this be a "just in case" shell. Elsewhere run sudo visudo and turn the flag off:
Defaults    !use_pty

Save the file, exit the editor. Check if sudo still works for your regular user. If it doesn't work then use the elevated shell to fix the sudoers file. Exit the elevated shell only after you confirm that sudo works for your regular user.

Note
With !use_pty, the command run with sudo may read directly from the terminal and consume what you pasted. A command run without sudo also may. Your example commands do not do this, but in general a command may. And if your sudo was going to ask for  password, it would also consume some part of what you pasted.
This is something the bracketed paste can solve. To avoid mishaps, enable bracketed paste in your Bash:
bind 'set enable-bracketed-paste on'

and make sure your terminal emulator uses the functionality when pasting. If bracketed paste works, a pasted multi-line snippet (like the one in question) will not be executed on the fly. It will be buffered by the shell and executed after you hit Enter. This way everything you paste will get to the shell, not to some pasted command that (if started early) would read from its stdin and consume the rest of the input.
With bracketed paste your snippet will work, no matter if use_pty is set or unset. For the reason explained in the cited manual it's good to set the flag.
Bracketed paste enabled and working, and use_pty set in sudoers is the safest, most robust setup when you want to paste multi-line snippets containing sudo. It will work properly even if sudo is going to ask for your password.
The concern from your comment "I don't see what output goes with what command" can be solved with set -v and/or set -x. See help set for details.
